# Destroy SWF DOM in swfupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, memory-leaks, swfupload

I am using swfupload for uploading files and I have this problem:

1. In Internet Explorer, I have to use destroy(). Otherwise it crashes
   http://demo.swfupload.org/Documentation/#destroy
2. In Firefox, if I use destroy(), it crashes.

So the solution is to detect browser type and only destroy in Internet Explorer. Is it how it works? Or did I do something wrong? I mean is the destroy() function only for IE??

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but try wrapping the SWF in another element and destroy that element.